# Long time running script while binding a view ? MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I been through lot of articles and i cant find anything suits the scenario

I have been getting `Long time ruuning script` which is i am unable to get rid of it .

I tried many ways to find out is there any continuous loop running in my script and i find nothing the Total time it took to load is a matter of `5 sec`

Later its trying to bind to view then here we go i get this issue its taking lot of time and once i click on `stop script` i can see data perfectly .

**My view :**

```
<table  data-bind="foreach:$root.MAINDATA">

    <tr>
        <td>
                @Html.Partial("Header");
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>
             <table>

                 <tr >
                     <td data-bind="foreach:$data.Data2"> 

                        <!-- ko if:Id === 1 -->
                          @Html.Partial("ONE") 
                         <!-- /ko -->

                         <!-- ko if:Id === 2 -->
                          @Html.Partial("TWO") 
                         <!-- /ko -->

                         <!-- ko if:Id === 4 -->
                          @Html.Partial("THREE")
                         <!-- /ko -->

                          <!-- ko if:Id === 5 -->
                          @Html.Partial("FOUR")
                         <!-- /ko -->
                          <!-- ko if:Id === 6 -->
                         @Html.Partial("FIVE")
                         <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if:Id === 7 -->
                         @Html.Partial("SIX")
                         <!-- /ko -->

                          <!-- ko if:Id === 8 -->
                         @Html.Partial("SEVEN")
                         <!-- /ko -->
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Well this is my main view and yes in deed it looks complex and each `@Html.Partial(//)` will have a views with 3 level deeper `data-bind:foreach:$data2` --> `data-bind:foreach:$data3` -- > `My controls` to show my view excatly .

See the way i am doing and building my `MAINDATA` observable array(it takes similar for loop structure with 7-10 ajax calls based on condition as in view) i just replicated to `bind` back to view .

I have no clue or whatsoever why this one is happening and people  around me suggested there may be a infinate loops blah blah i tried that but cant find anything .

**My observation :**

Do correct me if i'm wrong i believe when browser show loading means its tend to say proccess is happening in `script-controller` but after `5sec` there is no sign of browser showing any loading symbol and i get no display browser gets `hanged` when i click on ir i get `stop script` like that . I have to go with my gut feeling and say there is a issue while binding my view .

Any help is most appreciated .

Comment: Is "Long time ruuning script" the exact error? That's looks like a a Javascript warning. What javascript are you running? (you haven't posted any). Have you set a breakpoint in your javascript to see if it is..... _in an endless loop_

Comment: In excat localhost is not responding due to long running script (with stop script button). yes nick i checked as i also metioned in my observation time taken to complete all ajax calls in js file is `5sec` . but while binding its stuck sadly