# valueHasMutated is not working as expected?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I believe `valueHasMutated()` when applied on any observable or observableArray it will do a refresh/recheck i believe . In technical terms it notifies subscribers that they should re-evaluate .

**Viewmodel :**

```
var testing =function (){
var self=this;
self.status = ko.observable(1);
self.mainobseravle=ko.observableArray();

function subtest()
{
var self=this;
self.controlenable = ko.observable("");

self.statuschange = ko.computed(function(){
//Here i have to use `self.status` how can i use it below.  #1
//if(self.status == 1 || self.status==4)
{return true;} else {return false;}
});

}

}
```

My view binding based on `mainobservable` which have the object of `subtest` function .

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
//under success function
var d = new subtest();
d.controlenable(data.status);
self.mainobseravle.push(d); 
});
```

**View structure :**

```
<table data-bind="foreach:mainobseravle">
<tr><td> <input type="text" data-bind="enable:$data.controlenable" />  </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="forward" data-bind="click:$root.forward"/>
```

**Button Click :**

```
self.forward = function(){
// i change the status here
  self.status(2);
  self.mainobseravle.valueHasMutated(); // this goes fine and my controls still enabled #2 
}
```

Well let me make things more clear as i stored `self.status()` in a varaible and used inside `subtest` function and done everything and i hoped for a miracle i.e `valueHasMutated` works but nothing works .

As a scope issue i can't use `self.status()` directly inside `subtest` function . if you try it throws undefined error so thats why i am using a variable and alternative here ?

If i am missing anything important please do suggest .

Answer (score 1):

You're using `var self = this;`. The idea of this (often badly used) practise is that you store your context (what `this` points to) so you can use it inside functions that create their own closure. This would have given you what you need, however you made the mistake to redefine `self` in your `subtest` function. Try this:

```
var testing = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.status = ko.observable(1);
    self.mainobservable = ko.observableArray();

    self.forward = function () {
        self.status(2);
    };

    function subtest()
    {
        // removed var self = this; 
        this.controlenable = ko.observable("");    
        this.statuschange = ko.computed(function () {
            // This should now work, because 'self' points to 'testing' and not 'subtest'
            // I also made the code a bit shorter but it does exactly the same as your original code
            return (self.status == 1 || self.status == 4);
        });
        this.pushMeToMainObservable = function () {
            self.mainobservable.push(this);
        };
    }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    //under success function
    var d = new subtest();
    d.controlenable(data.status);
    d.pushMeToMainObservable (); 
});
```

I didn't really understand your questions, but this should help you along quite a bit. If fixes the scope issues, and you shouldn't need `valueHasMutated` if everything else works correctly.

For the record, your design is all wrong. Nesting `subtest` inside `testing` and then pushing an instance of `subtest` into the observable array inside `testing`... ouch... If you had a more modular structure, you would have less of these scope issues. I can't really go into much detail here because you 'abstracted' the names of your objects, and I have no idea what the big picture is in what you're trying to build. But `subtest` and `testing` are way too tightly coupled now. Their functionality is all mixed up.

Comment: thats one great insight and further more is function inside function  a bad practice ? i belive what i am trying to do here like `pushing an instance of subtest into the observable array inside testing.` . thats a dummy name but in real picture i have many functions with respective functions(view models) have the entities similar to class in controller having server model entities (server model) . onload i have many ajax calls where i get data and i should build my data in a observale array which is in main scope ..

Comment: if your are keen you can check my excat structure try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988238/long-time-running-script-while-binding-a-view-mvc . In this `self.MAINDATA` is my observale array i am talking to here . each partial view different function like `subtest` . i belive i have no choice i have to push my contructed data to observable array which is main function scope . by the way the looping structure will be 5 level deep . any suggestion is taken

Comment: I didn't mean that function inside function is bad (it isn't). However, your `subtest` has a computed that accesses `testing` (so `subtest` 'knows' `testing`). But `testing` also knows `subtest` since it stores `subtest` in the observable array. When two modules both need eachother, something is usually wrong. In this case `subtest` should NOT need to know `testing`, and therefore the computed observable should be placed inside of `testing`, and `subtest` should not push itself onto the observableArray in `testing`. Instead, you should do something like `testing.pushSubTest(new subtest());`

Comment: i agree with you completly . if you can clarify my query that would be great bro . 1) onload i have many ajax calls were i am trying to fill observable array `mainobservable ` using the created functions 2) coming to accessing `status` which is in `testing`function inside 'subtest' is a unavoidable situation becoz the `status` is used by 2 more pages in my module .

Comment: 3) most importnat , you said `computed observable should be placed inside of testing` i agree 100% but as per my thninking if i keep computed using `satus` which is in main function inside 'subtest' i get better control of hidding i guess else how ? how do i disable if i dont do like that .